# 2GB+ file upload options

Tags: php, upload, ftp

people, are there any other option except SWFupload to upload really huge files?
SWFupload works, but many people complaint often.

i need to show the progress of uploading to users also.

maybe i can somehow use FTP protocol? i know there are web based FTP clients out there.
what do you think?

Comment: vote me off topic, but are you sure you don't want to use Bittorrent for this, then you'll only need a small link + 1 long upload as long as you are seeding the torrent wil not die.

Answer (score 0):

Try the jQuery plugin [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/). It is easy to install, shows progress to users and has a troubleshooting faq [if you run into problems uploading large files](http://www.uploadify.com/faqs/why-does-uploadify-stop-when-trying-to-upload-large-files/).

Comment: Uploadify uses SWFUpload. I DONT WANT to use it since it can't handle 2GB+ files.

Comment: Sorry I glazed over that. For what it is worth my understanding is that the filesize limit is a limitation of your server, not swfupload/uploadify.

Comment: i triple checked all my settings. the thing is the swfupload is currently working on my website and everything is okay except 2gb+ files.

Comment: also i could not really find any adequate installation guide for the Uploadify :((

Comment: do you have a 32-bit server or 64-bit? and are you using a 32-bit or 64-bit client?